# I want to be able to write proof's for each of these but I don't know where to start.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

> Let $\mathrel{R_1}$ and $\mathrel{R_2}$ be relations on $\mathbb N$ defined by
>
> $x\mathrel{R_1}y$ if and only if $y = a + x$ for some $a \in\mathbb N_0$.
>
> $x\mathrel{R_2}y$ if and only if $y = xa$ for some $a \in\mathbb N$
>
> For all $x; y\in\mathbb N.$
>
> Also $\mathbb N_0$ denotes all integers $x\ge 0$, while $\mathbb N$ denotes all integers $x\ge 1$.

There are **four** different things I want to prove with this.

1. I want to show that $\mathrel{R_1}$ is a partial order on $\mathbb N$.
2. I want to show that $\mathrel{R_2}$ is a partial order on $\mathbb N$.
3. I want to show that $\mathrel{R_2}\subseteq\mathrel{R_1}$.
4. Finally I want to show that $\mathrel{R_1}$ is a total order.

---

For the first proof that $\mathrel{R_1}$ is a partial order I need to show that $\mathrel{R}$ is Reflexive, Anti-Symmetric, and Transitive, and the same goes for R2.

$\mathrel R$ is reflexive: for all $a\in A, a\mathrel Ra$.

$\mathrel R$ is antisymmetric: for all $a,b\in A$, if $a\mathrel Rb$ and $b\mathrel Ra$, then it must be the case that $a=b$.

$\mathrel R$ is transitive: for all $a,b,c\in A$, if $a\mathrel Rb$ and $b\mathrel Rc$, then $a\mathrel Rc$.

Unfortunately my problem is every time I write a proof I fail miserably because I don't have anything to base off of. I understand how it should work I just don't understand how to correctly write it.

In order to show that $\mathrel{R_2}\subseteq\mathrel{R_1}$ this means that everything that is in $\mathrel{R_2}$ must be in $\mathrel{R_1}$?

The last part has me very confused because I have to show that $\mathrel{R_1}$ is a total order. I think this means that I have to show that it is Anti-Symmetric, Transitive, and a totality. I wouldn't know where to start for this.

---

What I need overall is help with forming with these proof's and to see if someone could give me a guide line sort of basis to perform my work off of.

Comment: Can you explain in plain english why $R_1$ and $R_2$ are partial orders? Once you understand *why* they are, writing down a formal proof is much easier.... Also, regarding $R_1$, have you look at what that relation actually says? Hint: It's a relation you very dealing with quite often....

Answer (score 0):

**Ḧints:**

1. $x=0+x$ and $x=1x$.  What does this mean?
2. If $y=a+x$ and $x=b+y$ then $x=(a+b)+x$.  What does this mean?
3. If $y=ax$ and $a\ge1$ then $y=(a-1)x+x$. What does this mean?